# In Rails 5, setting config.active_record.schema_format = :sql but still getting schema.rb created on db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, schema.rb

Working on a Rails 5 app, I want to use `structure.sql` instead of `schema.rb` (we're using PostGIS with lots of custom SQL calls...).  In `config/initializers/database_options.rb` I have the following:

```
# use structure.sql, not schema.rb
Rails.application.config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

If I run the following:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

it generates `db/schema.rb`, ***not*** `db/structure.sql`.

The rails guides say:

> There are two ways to dump the schema. This is set in
>   config/application.rb by the config.active_record.schema_format
>   setting, which may be either :sql or :ruby.

What magic am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should put your rails component config before `Initializers`.
The rails application initialize by the following order.

- config/application.rb
- Environment-specific configuration files
- Initializers
- After-initializers

You could put your config `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` either in `config/application.rb` or `config/environments/development.rb` depends on environment you used.

That should work.

Answer (score 3):

In your initializer do:

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
end
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer, since that notified me and I realized that I hadn't ever accepted bananaappletw's answer.  The problem I had was that I was setting this in an initializer (as you suggest as well), but it needs to be in either `config/application.rb` or one of the environment configs.

Comment: The solution I posted works for me in an initializer.