# How to debug rails db:structure:dump?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the line `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` in my application.rb file but I'm still having the problem that when I type `rails db:migrate` it doesn't output the :sql version. In fact it doesn't output anything. When I type in `rails db:structure:dump` it doesn't output anything either. However, when I type in `rails db:schema:dump` it outputs the schema.rb file. I'm using postgresql and rails 5.0.

It seems to me that for some reason `rails db:structure:dump` is not working but I don't know how to debug this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
~/main$ rails db:schema:dump --trace
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

Similar but different question:
[In Rails 5, setting config.active_record.schema_format = :sql but still getting schema.rb created on db:migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369035/in-rails-5-setting-config-active-record-schema-format-sql-but-still-getting)

Comment: It's possible that got over-ruled somewhere else. Are there any references to `schema_format` in your code elsewhere?

Comment: @tadman there is no where else in the code where you have schema_format. Do you have any tips for how to debug this?

Comment: First thing I usually try is to check on another project to see if I can reproduce it. The next thing I do is upgrade Rails to the latest version that doesn't break anything. 5.0 is pretty old now, so there could be bugs.