# Why does rails generate a schema.rb file even with schema format set to sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am running `Rails 6.1.6` on `ruby -v 2.7.1`.

I set this in my `application.rb` file

```rb
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

I tried to run my migrations but `schema.rb` gets generated even as the existing `structure.sql` file gets updated accordingly.

Extra info: I observed this behaviour when I upgraded to `Rails 6.1` from `5.2`.

I don't suppose `schema.rb` should ever be generated when `schema_format` is set to `:sql`. When I tried to set `config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration` to `false`. My `structure.sql` file does not get updated.

What may I be missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Rails 5, setting config.active\_record.schema\_format = :sql but still getting schema.rb created on db:migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369035/in-rails-5-setting-config-active-record-schema-format-sql-but-still-getting)

Comment: Are you using `hairtrigger` gem? If so, [it could be causing this issue](https://github.com/jenseng/hair_trigger/issues/93). And [fix was only merged this year in January](https://github.com/jenseng/hair_trigger/pull/113/files)!